# "Angularjs" How to separate out directive and controller in the same file into different files

Tags: angularjs, controller, leaflet, mapbox, directive

I'm new to angularjs and I was working on implementing the map using leaflet && Mapbox. I'm trying to follow this example from here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

Above example is basically javascript codes, but what I'm trying to do is to do it in a angular way.

Here is a working example I was working on, and shows the map:

`plunker`    http://plnkr.co/edit/V2yWoV5eeH7oaGYzXjHW?p=preview

I have two questions.

**First**: How do you separate out directive and controller codes in "app.js" into appropriate files? I know they are not supposed to be in one file, and I want to see an example how to do it properly. I'd appreciate it if you could show me in Plunker or etc.

**Second**: When you take a look at the site I linked above (leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html), in *Basic States Map* section, a geoJSON data is added(us-states.js). How do you add this line of code "L.geoJson(statesData).addTo(map);" into my working example?

your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should isolate your question to one topic rather multiple completely separate problems of a) structuring your code across multiple files and b) a Leaflet app related problem. "I have two questions" should have flagged that you create 2 separate questions. I suggest removing one and creating another question.

Comment: Answer to your first question: you just create two additional JS files, cut and paste the code of the controller to one and the code of the directive to the other, and ass <script> elements in the HTML page for these two files.